# Retrieve email addresses from People picker within a Repeating Table

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath

I have created a form that includes a people picker within a repeating table.

The idea behind this is that it will be able to send information held within the form to each person that the person creating the form thinks is involved in the task.

The issue i face is that the people picker indirectly holds the email addresses and I cannot seem to pick all of them up.

I am trying to get them into a different field in the format jbloggs@gmail.com; tsmith@gmail.com; jjames@gmail.com

If anybody can help me with this task i would very much appreciate it (all email addresses have been made up from common names)

EDIT - This is a custom form published to a SharePoint Library which is causing all the issues with this.  If a multiple selection people picker would work, solutions using that method would be welcome.

Comment: my current thought process is along the lines of the accountID, as when in SharePoint this picks up the email address for an individual, however  i dont know how this would work as the people picker is within a repeating table.

Comment: Seems like this might have to be done using sharepoint workflows, but in this regard i dont know how to pick up more than just the information in the first row of the repeating table.  If anybody has experience or knowledge of this please let me know

Comment: One person per people picker in the repeating table?

Comment: Yeah, that's how i'm envisioning this working.  Each row having 1 people picker with 1 person per row

Comment: Never had an actual case where i needed to use a repeating table so correct me if i'm wrong. Each row in a repeating table creates a new list item right?

Comment: correct,and it follows the same layout as the template row/s

Comment: Any specific reason to add a new list item per user added? Wouldn't a multiple people picker field work? Trying to get a brief picture of what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: i could use multiple people in one people picker, however i am left with the issue of getting email addresses from the account id's still.  
I thought that multiple rows would be more user friendly, but either would work

Comment: I actually think that one people column that allows multiple persons would suit your needs. If you are sending the mail from SPD, are you sure that you are trying to set up the workflow correctly? Just set up a infopath form, with one people picker field and added 3 people. Configured a workflow to send a mail to the users in that field which worked fine. http://imgur.com/a/IAWhU

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65110/discussion-between-c-shanks-and-christoffer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An update for everyone - Because of time pressure on this task I have resorted to a rudimentary method of having 8 separate people picker fields with a workflow to email the person identified in each field.

If extra people are required in a task, I still have a people picker in a repeating table, but the people identified in the repeating table field are not receiving emails via the workflows.

Comment: have you created a custom form for this?

Comment: Yes, this was stated in a previous edit to my question after a conversation with another user